# Entity Framework Core InMemory DbContext DbSet return empty

Tags: entity-framework-core

I implement EF Core with `InMemory`, when I try to query all the records, it returns empty, but there are values in `DbSet.Local` property.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my DbSet

```
public DbSet<Ads> Advertisements { get; set; }
```

Is it caused by using `UseInMemoryDatabase`?

```
_options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SensingSiteDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase()
            .Options;
```

Comment: This could easily happen with real databases too, for instance if all the entities in DbSet.Local are in the `Added` state. How are you creating those entities? (BTW, there's a visible e-mail address in that image. If that's not intentional, you may want to remove it.)

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. I did not savechanges after add new records.